# 'int' object is not subscriptable (scraping tables from website)

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am painfully new to coding... I just learned how to use the terminal approximately one week ago if that gives you any idea of how n00bish I am. I need to learn how to scrape data from websites so I am practicing on websites that I am familiar with, and I'm trying to create a csv file that shows the data from this url: http://phish.net/song. I essentially modified code from this site (https://chihacknight.org/blog/2014/11/26/an-intro-to-web-scraping-with-python.html) and I'm trying to use it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "http://phish.net/song?"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")
table = soup.find('table')
rows = table.find('tr')
data = {
'song': [],
'original_artist': [],
'times': [],
'debut': [],
'last': [],
'gap': []
}
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find('td')
    data['song'].append(cols[0].get_text()))
    data['original_artist'].append(cols[1].get_text())
    data['times'].append(cols[2].get_text())
    data['debut'].append(cols[3].get_text())
    data['last'].append(cols[4].get_text())
    data['gap'].append(cols[5].get_text())
phishData = pd.DataFrame(data)
phishData.to_csv("PhishData.csv")
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phishnet.py", line 20, in <module>
    data['song'].append(str(cols[0].get_text()))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Which object is the one that's not subscriptable? And how do I fix this problem? Thanks in advance for your help and please tell me if this is not an appropriate use of this forum.

Comment: Check what is being returned for `cols[0]`.  That seems to be returning an `int` object instead of a BeautifulSoup object as you expected.

Comment: The output is this:
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1
None
-1

But I'm afraid I'm not sure why that's happening...

Comment: `.find` retuens a `Tag` object or `None`. Instead, you should use `find_all`, which returns a list of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pd.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) seems to do what you want.

```
df = pd.read_html("http://phish.net/song?")[0]
```

```
df.head()
          Song Name Original Artist                 Times       Debut  \
0      Alumni Blues           Phish                   107  1985-03-16   
1     And So To Bed           Phish  Found in Discography         NaN   
2  You Enjoy Myself           Phish                   581  1986-02-03   
3         AC/DC Bag           Phish                   310  1986-04-01   
4    F**k Your Face           Phish                    13  1987-04-29   

         Last   Gap  
0  2017-07-29  13.0  
1         NaN   NaN  
2  2017-12-31   0.0  
3  2017-12-28   3.0  
4  2017-08-05   8.0
```

And, the final `to_csv` call -

```
df.to_csv("PhishData.csv")
```

Comment: Wow, that makes my life very easy. I'll play around with this more, thank you!

Comment: @Hannah You're welcome! When you reach 15 rep, please consider voting on my answer as well. Thank you.